# Best way to get the sub-path for getExternalFilesDir()?

Tags: android

`getExternalFilesDir(type)` returns a path on the primary "external" storage. I need my app to store files in real external storage (i.e. an SD Card), but I'd still like to use the correct directory structure for app data. What's the best way to get the sub-path relative to the storage directory?

I'm currently doing this:

```
// for type = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC
// extPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Music"
String extPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(type).toString();
int extStoragePathLen = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString().length();
// subPath = "/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Music"
String subPath = extPath.substring(extStoragePathLen, extPath.length());
File sdCardPath = new File(getRealExternalStorageDirectory(), subPath);
```

Note: I'm not using `Context.getExternalFilesDirs(type)` because it only works for SDK >= KitKat and is therefore probably unusable for the next 5 or 6 years until KitKat is the really old Android version of the day.

Comment: Your solution looks okay, but what is `getRealExternalStorageDirectory()` and why do you need to overwrite android's wish where you should place files?

Comment: don't forget that a lot of devices does not have an SD-card slot.

Comment: `getRealExternalStorageDirectory()` is a method to return the path to secondary storage or an SD Card if available. It actually falls back to the emulated external directory if no sd card is present or available. My app is a custom side-loaded app and we'll almost always side-load install it on devices with an SD Card.

Comment: Real external storage was not properly supported, so there is no "correct" `/Android/data/` path. You might be the only app that uses this path on SD card. It's also simply hardcoded in Android to android data + `context.getPackagename()`. [some source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Environment.java/#132)

Comment: @zapl, when I say "correct," I simply mean whatever path the APIs return on the current device.

Comment: The APIs don't make `subPath` available, especially the `/Android/data` part is usually just hardcoded without even using constants that could be used from somewhere else. The same applies to `files`. The only parts available are `Context#getPackageName()` and `Environment.DIRECTORY_*` which are the actual folder names i.e. `Music` in your case. The point of "correct" I meant: the APIs return a path valid for primary storage, real external storage is pure anarchy and there is not much point in using what should have been the path the API would return if it supported external storage.

Comment: @zapl, I think that Google intends for that to change now that they have `getExternalFilesDirs(type)`. I can't test it because I don't have a KitKat device and I can't figure out how to get avd to support additional external storage areas.

Comment: Yes, that would be the all new api. The old one is "broken" since Honeycomb's [unified storage](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/) that made external live on internal storage since data / apps on actually removable storage results in lots of problems since nobody really handles such exceptions correctly.